# Error when deleting dynamic array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I am getting a run time error when my program hits this code. I am sure the delete is causing it, I just don't see what is going wrong.

Here is the function: (FavShows is a class defined earlier)

```
void classInit()
{
    int numOfRecs;
    cout << "How many records will you enter?" << endl;
    cin >> numOfRecs;
    FavShows *m = new FavShows[numOfRecs];

    for( int i = 0; i < numOfRecs; i++)
    {
        m[i].initRec();
    }

for( int i = 0; i < numOfRecs; i++)
{
    m[i].printRec();
}
delete m;
}
```

The error I receive states:
the error is in dbgdel.cpp ( i assume this is a memeber of one of the libs)
Expression:_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Comment: should call `delete [] m`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `std::vector`, avoid the pain.

---

For the code as given, note a `new[]` needs a `delete[]`, not plain single-object `delete`.

---

With a `std::vector` it's much easier to just **count** the records entered by the user, instead of asking up-front how many. For each record inputted, use `push_back` to add it to the end of the vector. Then starting with an empty vector.

Comment: FACEPALM, Thanks, that fixed it, I must be getting tired!

Comment: I will give it a try, we havnt covered vectors yet, but our final will give extra credit if we utilize a vector. Thanks for the help